# What is the correct Homebrew Installation command for an M1 Mac mini and Big Sur?

Tags: bash, mac, git

After reinstalling the whole M1 Mac mini, Big Sur and Migration Assistant for this morning's Time Machine's backup, I'm getting a new error when installing Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash: line 156: /usr/local/bin/git: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Then…

```
Failed during: git init -q
```

I don't see actions to take if these come up.

Comment: “Bad CPU type in executable” in means that the Git you have installed is most likely for Intel CPUs and you need to install the one for M1 CPUs. Try running `xcode-select --install` from the terminal and see what happens.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact command you're using to install homebrew

Comment: It's safe to presume that OP is using the one command that Homebrew gives for its own installation—on both Intel and M1 Macs: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem on my new MacBookPro (M1 MAX - Monterey).
I installed Rosetta 2 as advised in this article: https://linuxpip.org/fix-bad-cpu-type-in-executable/ with the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Then Homebrew installation went through.

I assume the OP uses the official Homebrew install command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```